What is the current state of outbound TLS SNI support among mail servers?
I'm researching the current state of TLS SNI (Server Name Indication) usage in email infrastructure, specifically focusing on outbound connections from mail servers in SMTPS and SMTP with STARTTLS protocols.
I'm less interested in which mail server software supports SNI, and more in how many operational mail servers are actually configured to use it for outgoing mail. Any data, personal experiences from large-scale email operations, or pointers to relevant research would be greatly appreciated

Any MTA supporting MTA-STS MUST use SNI for this - see RFC 8461 sect 7.1.  So if you get any statistics for MTA-STS support than this can be considered a lower bound.

@SteffenUllrich thank you for your response! I've noticed some interesting points in the specifications that I'd like to clarify. On one hand, it states that clients are required (they MUST do it) to use SNI when establishing a TLS connection with a server. However, it also mentions that servers MUST NOT mandate SNI usage by clients.
In my specific use case, I'd like to ensure that clients always send SNI information. Do you know any other ways to make clients send SNI?

There is no way to force the client (MUA or MTA acting as client) to use SNI, neither at the TLS level nor at the SMTP level. All what one can do if SNI is essential for operation is to fail the TLS handshake.
